# ssh into mac from raspberry pi

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, sshfs, macos

I am trying to mount a shared drive that exists on my mac in my raspberry pi. I tried searching many different threads on stackoverflow and stackexchange and couldn't find any working solutions. I followed this guide: [nixCraft sshfs](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-mount-remote-directory-filesystems-with-sshfs-on-linux/) and tried the steps outlined in: [SSH Permission denied (publickey) [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060046/ssh-permission-denied-publickey/30060109?noredirect=1#comment106168045_30060109). I am able to perform the reverse; ssh into rpi from my mac (as well as win10 pc). Apologize if people consider this a duplicate, but I commented on another thread asking for some assistance, however I was told to post a new question.

This is what I tried:

```
sshfs -o debug username@192.168.0.10:/raspi_pyfies ~/mount/ssh_macdr
```

which gave me:

```
FUSE library version: 2.9.9
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
username@192.168.0.10: Permission denied (publickey).
read: Connection reset by peer
```

I also just tried `ssh`ing:

```
ssh -v username@192.168.0.10
```

and it gave me (last few lines):

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:#####
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
username@192.168.0.10: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Hopefully someone with experience can shed some light. Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the pi's public key to the MAC's `authorized_keys` file?

Comment: hi yes i did. i generated key pair from scratch. not sure what else to try

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [one of the answers to your linked question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30061063/12231187), run:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

When it asks for file in which to save the key, enter `id_rsa`. It's also OK to enter nothing, if you're OK with overwriting them under `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

When it asks for a passphrase, leave it empty.

Concatenate the `id_rsa.pub` file to the end of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the destination machine. Then test from the originating machine using

```
ssh -i id_rsa user@host
```

If `id_rsa` is located in `~/.ssh` then you can omit the `-i` option:

```
ssh user@host
```

Then you've verified `scp`, `sftp` and `sshfs` will all work.

Important: `ssh` will **not** work if permissions on critical paths are too permissive or too restrictive. The file modes must be set as:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 644 authorized_keys
chmod 600 id_rsa
chmod 644 id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: hi Curt, thanks for your response. I did try all those suggestions before when I searched other threads. I remove .ssh; then re-did everything from scratch. I kept on getting permission denied. I also tried changing the permissions as well. I didn't try different permissions for different files, however. I tried that just now; but no luck.

Comment: Shoot. It does look like the Pi offered the key `id_rsa` and it was refused. Do you have other hosts that can ssh into the Mac? Maybe turn on debugging on the Mac side (add `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart ssh) and examine the system log.

Comment: i added the `DEBUG3` to the sshd_config file. It was already at `DEBUG`, i just added the `3`. Where can I view the logs?

Comment: so I found the log in `system.log`:  `Feb  3 21:11:56 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd): Unknown key for string: SHAuthorizationRight
Feb  4 21:24:37 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd): Unknown key for string: SHAuthorizationRight
Feb  4 21:41:44 username com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.###): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
Feb  4 21:48:47 username com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.###): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
`

Comment: i substituted jargon characters for the hastags so that it would fit as a comment

Comment: All right, I don't do Apple, so a couple more things and I'm afraid I'll have to say something lame like ask on https://discussions.apple.com. The SHAuthorizationRight seems to be a red herring. I did find one reference that says it's a firewall problem. The firewall needs to allow launchd rather than sshd.